Let $x_0 = 3;\ x_{n+1}=3x_n\ $ if $\ \frac{x_n}{2}<1;\ x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{2}\ $ if $\ \frac{x_n}{2}>1.\ $ Is $\ \liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n=1?$
This is a natural follow-up question of this previous question of mine.
Let $x_0 = 3.$ Let $\ x_{n+1} = 3x_n\ $ if $\ \frac{x_n}{2}<1;\quad x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n}{2}\ $ if $\ \frac{x_n}{2}>1.\quad $ Is $\ \displaystyle\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = 1?$
I don't think the proposition follows from either of the answers to my previous question, but maybe I am missing something.
I tried testing this algorithm with a calculator, but couldn't conclude either way after $40$ or so iterations, at which point the calculator has probably lost some accuracy of the value of $x_n.$

Doesn't it follow from $\log 3 / \log 2 $ is irrational, and $ { n \alpha } $ is dense in $[0,1]$?

@CalvinLin Please can you explain how.

I believe you first need to take a log, then it will be clear why Calvin's argument jumps in.

Let $ y_n = \log x_n$. Then the problem transforms into:

$ y_0 = \log 3 $.
$y_{n+1} = y_n + \log 3 $ if $ y_n < \log 2 $.
$ y_{n+1} = y_n - \log 2 $ if $ y_n > \log 2 $.
Is $ \liminf y_n = 0 $?

Note that $y_n \geq 0$.
Claim: For each positive integer $k$, show that there exists an $m_k$ such that $$y_{m_k} = \quad k \log 3 \pmod{ \log 2 } \in [0, \log 2 ).$$
(Note that I don't just want $y_{m_k} {\color{red} \equiv} k \log 3 \pmod {\log 2}$.)

 We're adding $ \log 3 $ one at a time, and subtracting $\log 2$ one at a time.
 So there is some $y_m \equiv k \log 3 \pmod{ \log 2 } $.
 In the next few steps, we will have reduced it to the desired value of  $ y_{m_k} = k \log 3 \pmod{\log 2 } $.

Corollary: Since $ \frac{ \log 3 } { \log 2 } $ is irrational, hence $ k \log 3  \pmod{\log 2 } $ is dense in $[0, \log 2 )$, and so $\lim \inf y_n = 0$.

Bonus: Determine the value of $m_k$.

 $$m_k = k + \lfloor \frac{ k \log 3 } { \log 2 }  \rfloor,$$
 because we need to add $ \log 3 $ by $k$ times  and also subtract $\log 2 $ by $\lfloor \frac{ k \log 3 } { \log 2 }  \rfloor$ times.
 We do not need to know the explicit order in which the steps happen, we just need to know that each step happens so many times.


When you say $y_{m_k}=k\log(3)\pmod{\log(2)}$, do you mean that $0\le y_{m_k}\lt\log(2)$?

@robjohn Yes I do. Hence the equality sign (and the space to try to make it clear that I want it to be that value).

It took me a while, but I finally get this.

@AdamRubinson Any parts that you think could be improved on / more details added?

Maybe a formal proof of why there exists an $m_k$ such that $y_{m_k} = \quad k \log 3 \pmod{ \log 2 }$.

@AdamRubinson Sure. Based on what was written up, I added an explicit calculation for the value of $m_k$ in the second hidden block.
